# How remove whitespace during typing in Xamarin Forms(MVVM)

Tags: c#, xamarin

I want to add a function, when the user enters the login will be deleted spaces.
How remove whitespace during typing in Xamarin Forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your ViewModel you can have the property Username binded to Entry like this:

```
private string _username;
public bool Username
{
    get { return _username; }
    set
    {
        string tmp = value;
        _username= tmp.Replace(" ", String.Empty);;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}

<Entry Text="{Binding Username}" />
```

I assume that you have implemented OnPropertyChanged() event and your BindingContext is properly set in your Model.